# MySQL - Return all columns where bit is equal to 1

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with a table that contains 50 columns (with bit values), for each 50 U.S. state. I'm trying to find an SQL statement that will return all columns containing a 1. I've looked around for ways of doing this with no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: This violates the [Zero, One or Infinite Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) and proper [database normalization principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If you're not too married to the schema, I'd change it to something easier to query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a new development, and not for existing tables I would suggest the following. (Otherwise I'm stumped.) It sounds like you have implemented a many-to-many. I would suggest that you implement a table for States as suggested by @juergen d (albeit without the bit field); implement your current entity as-is but without the columns for states. And then implement a third table that has two columns, one for a state's ID and another for the ID of your entity.

Then instead of setting bit fields on your entity's table, you would create entries in this third table.

You can then perform joins on tables to obtain the states set on a certain entity.

For more info see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model) and http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/inner-vs-outer-joins-on-a-many-to-many-relationship

Comment: If you are however stuck with the current schema I would suggest vigorous use of a text editor to query each bit column separately and concatenate the results as text.

Answer (score 3):

You should better change your table design. Better use something like this

```
States table
-------------------
id       int
name     varchar(100)
bitcol   bit(1)
```

Then you could select that states like this

```
select name from States
where bitcol = 1
```